# Current Conveyor CCII internal circuital realization

Tags: transistors, mosfet, integrated-circuit, circuit-design, cmos

I have read [this article](http://ecad.tu-sofia.bg/et/2009/ET_2009/AEM2009_2/Circuits%20and%20Systems/73-Paper-R_Prokop1.pdf) about current conveyor CCII, and I have some problems about understanding its circuital realization (page 4):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fU8Teu.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The article says:

> The feedback of opamp structure [this expression refers to the circuit shown above]
> copies the voltage from input “Y” to the input “X” and at
> the same time guarantees a very low impedance at the input
> “X” node. The current from the input “X” is then conveyed
> by the transistors M5, M6 and corresponding current
> mirrors M7, M8 to the output “Z”. In the shown circuit the
> “push-pull” transistor branches were used.

Can you explain me in a more detailed way? Why the voltage at X is the same of that at Y? And why the current on Z is the same of that on X?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Kinka-Byo, remember the classical opamp with feedback.

- The transistors M1, M2, M5 and M6 form a high-gain amplifier (output node: between M5 and M6) - and the connection between the output node and the input X provides 100% negative feedback (the input X acts as an inverting input). Hence, as for the classical opamp the input voltage at Y (non-inverting) is amplified with "1" (unity gain amplifier) and the output voltage is also identical to the voltage at X.
- According to system theory (and for current feedback), the input resistance at the feedback node is lowered by a factor which is identical to the loop gain. For a high loop gain, the input resistance (at X) is considerably lowered.
- The combination M7/M8 is identical to M5/M6 and both combinations receive the same input at the base nodes. Therefore, when there is a current through the input X we have the same current through a load that is connected to the high-resistive output Z.

Answer (score 3):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fKdw6M.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The circuit can be interactively simulated above, and I recommend everyone who hasn't dealt with conveyors to play with it. It's a very useful circuit.

Note how this circuit resembles **an ideal NPN bipolar transistor**: Y is the base, X is the emitter, Z is collector. \$V_{BE}\approx 0 {\,\rm V},\ r_E\approx 4 \,\Omega \$.

Its function - or specification - is as follows.

1. The input Y has high impedance and is a voltage input.
2. The voltage Y is copied to input X.
3. The current on input X is sensed.
4. The voltage copied to Z is \$V_Z = V_Y + I_X \cdot R_O\$, where \$R_O\$ is the output impedance, finite but small. The output impedance depends on the impedances of the output elements, and is typically in the 1-100 Ohm ballpark in ICs.
5. Equivalently, we can say that the output is a voltage source with a very low ESR, such that when loaded with an ideal voltage source of Y volts, the current X will flow through the output.

The conveyor as simulated above has about 3.6 Ohms of output impedance. The voltage and current setpoints are 4.5V and 30mA. 30mA flowing across 3.6 Ohms is 0.108V. So, the conveyor behaves as-if it was a 4.5V+0.108V=4.608V voltage source with a 3.6Ohm ESR.

> Why the voltage at X is the same of that at Y?

M5 and M6 are an output stage that does it, driven by the differential amplifier M1-M2.

> why the current on Z is the same of that on X?

It's not actually the same except if Z is connected to an ideal voltage source of voltage Y.

Z acts like a voltage source with a low-but-nonzero internal resistance \$R_O\$, with a voltage \$V_{ZI} = V_Y + R_O\cdot I_X\$.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fhGTIO.png)</sup>

It acts so, because M5/M6 and M7/M8 are driven with the same gate voltages, and act like voltage sources with the same output impedance.

M5/M6 are loaded with current X, and thanks to the amplifier action of M1 and M2 are driven to produce voltage Y on the X input.

If you then load M7/M8 at the output Z with the same current, you'll get the same voltage. Or, conversely, if you load the output Z with an ideal voltage source set to Y, you'll get current X.

X and Y are effectively both outputs and have the same output voltage when loaded with same current. The current on X determines the operating point current on Z, because the *voltage* on X is controlled to be the same as the voltage on Y. To "swap" X and Z, all it takes is connecting the gate of M1 to Z instead of X.

---

I've put this CCII together using three CD4007UB CMOS transistor arrays.

At 4V Y voltage, +1mA X current, the performance is as follows:

- the X-Y offset is about 13mV,
- the short circuit Z-to-GND current is 3.06mA,
- the open circuit Z voltage is 2.7V below Y voltage,
- the output resistance, based on open circuit voltage, is about 2.7kOhm.

The simulation below doesn't use MOS transistors with parameters from CD4007UB, so it looks "better". CD4007UB transistors have fairly high channel resistance compared to modern small-signal amplifier mosfets.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fu4RQ4.png)</sup>

The breadboard layout is below. U1 through U3 is left to right. POT1 is on the bottom, POT2 is on the top. The voltmeter probes are connected between GND and Z output.

The TO-92 part is an LM334 current source, programmed to 50uA by the nearby resistor.

[image: The top view of the assembled conveyor on a solderless breadboard]